# How to call Databricks dbutils using Scala Reflection / Mirrors

Tags: scala, reflection, databricks, scala-reflect, dbutils

I want to call

```
com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "myScope", key = "myKey")
```

using mirroring.

So far I achieve this:

```
val className = "com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder"

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val moduleSymbol = mirror.staticModule(className)
val moduleMirror = mirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(moduleMirror.instance)
```

This delivers a valid dbutils reference:

```
instanceMirror.instance
> Any = com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder$@25d7f14b
```

As comparison:

```
com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder
> com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.type = com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder$@25d7f14b
```

To list the available fields:

```
val fields = moduleSymbol.typeSignature.decls.filter(_.asTerm.isVal)
for (f <- fields) {
    println(f)
    val fieldMirror = instanceMirror.reflectField(f.asTerm)
}
> value dbutils0
> value dbutils
```

The question is how to extend the *fieldMirror* to access dbutils.secrets.get(s, k)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fieldMirror.get.asInstanceOf[...].secrets.get(scope = "myScope", key = "myKey")
```

where you should cast (`fieldMirror.get.asInstanceOf[...]`) `dbutils` to its type.

I assume that you know the type of `dbutils` statically. Otherwise accessing `dbutils.secrets.get(s, k)` will be a little harder (and then you should provide more details about `dbutils`, `secrets`, `.get` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

DBUtilsHolder is a trait. We need to find the in which acutal companinon object `secrets.get()` method is implemented, to be able to apply a run time reflection.

Till then other way to use it is a to directly access the jar from Databricks using sbt, Maven, or Gradle without reflection.
For Spark 3.0 and above, download the jar from the Databricks CLI and use it until they release it formally.